# Matlab: How to merge the values of struct array fields

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

Is it possible to easily combine values from struct array fields into a single array without looping through each individual struct in the array?

For reference, see the attached code:

```
% build random struct array with only one field
% for demonstration only
clear i s out;
for i = 1:10
    s(i).value = rand;
end
s

% not working, as it returns multiple results
s(1:end).value

% combine all "value" into a single array using for-loop
out = zeros(length(s), 1);
for i = 1:length(s)
    out(i) = s(i).value;
end
out
```

Simply put, the goal is to kind of "merge" all "value" fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using the following:

```
out = [s.value]
```

The `s.value` returns all the values and `[...]` to make an array of them.

Comment: I was absolutely sure that I did try this, but obviously I was wrong. Thanks!
For completeness: The (:) is not needed, only the [...]